# React Native - TextInput inlineImageLeft not working

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to add an image to left of my TextInput field but it's not working. I already tried putting the path, just the name of the image and also tried with `require('path/to/image')` but nothing seems to work.

I have something like this

```
<TextInput
    value={this.state.value}
    onChangeText={ (value) => this.setState({value})
    inlineImageLeft="path/to/image"
/>
```

Comment: This property is Android-only, and was added to React Native in version 0.30. Are you trying this on iOS or Android, and which version of RN are you using?

Comment: Ahh that's why is not working, I have version 0.29. Thank you!

Comment: @jevakallio still not working, upgraded to rn 0.31.0 but still not working, do you know how to properly use this property?

Comment: I haven't used it myself, so not sure what the correct way is.

Comment: @jevakallio I see, thank you

Answer (score 2):

UIExplorer has an example on it, under the title 'Inline Images'.

```
react-native/Examples/UIExplorer/js/TextInputExample.android.js
```

It seems path should be relative to `./android/app/src/main/res/drawable/`. Any other path does not work. Also image does not scale.

```jsx
<TextInput inlineImageLeft="ic_menu_black_24dp"/>
```

Comment: hi, did you manage to get this working ? i cant seem to. i placed image.png in ./res/drawable .. ; image size is 20px; i set prop like this:  inlineImageLeft="image.png" . is any special naming convention required perhaps ?

Answer (score 2):

follow the react native documentation and after adding images to drawable folder **clean the project from build option in android studio and rerun the project** with react-native run-android. it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the optimal solution but it worked for me. I created a [flex](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html) with the icon on the left and the [TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#inlineimageleft) on the right. I styled it to my liking and created a box with a white background that encompasses both. Here is my css styling code:

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#f5f7fa',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
inputBox: {
    flex: 0,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '90%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 4,
    margin: 5,
    borderColor: '#c4c6c8',
    borderWidth: 1,
},
textInputs: {
    height: 60,
    width: '86%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 4,
    color: '#c4c6c8',
}
```

If you are not familiar with Flexbox, you can also look at the following article:
https://medium.com/@drorbiran/the-full-react-native-layout-cheat-sheet-a4147802405c 
and this website let's you play with the properties in live mode:
http://flexbox.buildwithreact.com/

I hope this helps :)